# Apache Beam TextIO PCollection of files instead of lines

Tags: regex, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using Apache Beam Java SDK 2.1.0

We have several error logs in a bucket of Google Cloud storage, we are reading all the files in this path, with TextIO.read

We need to aggregate them in order to find errors in messages being sent. We have a regex that works, filtering different lines from each file, the problem is that with the nature of `TextIO.read` we get a `PCollection` of lines, so when try to apply the regex in the `pardo`, its processing it  line by line and the Regex never finds a match.

Regex: `"MESSAGE:(.*)\\n\\[MESSAGE\\].*(\\\"entityName\\\":\\\"\\w+\\\")"`

Is there anyway that `TextIO.read` returns a `PCollection` of files, one file per element so then when it gets the `parDo` we have access to complete element?

As a plan b, is there a way to combine all the lines of each file into one, with Apache Beam, so the regex pattern works?

```
public static class ExtractWordsFn extends DoFn<String, String> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        final String regex = "MESSAGE:(.*)\\n\\[MESSAGE\\].*(\\\"entityName\\\":\\\"\\w+\\\")";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(c.element());
        List<String> entities = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + m.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                entities.add(m.group(i));
            }
        }

        // Output each word encountered into the output PCollection.
        for (String entity : entities) {
            c.output(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`TextIO.readAll()`, available in Beam 2.2 (release is currently ongoing but you can already use it from a snapshot version or build from github), reads a `PCollection` of filepatterns or filenames.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to use it from Google Cloud Dataflow?

Comment: Yes, Apache Beam *is* the SDK for Dataflow. Just specify the dataflow runner in your Beam pipeline the usual way.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but didn't manage to make it work, after cloning Beam 2.2 and Dataflow 2.2 got several errors while trying to run mvn install, even trying different branches, I end creating a python script for this

Comment: OK. I suggest to try again after Beam 2.2 is released (a number of difficulties have been delaying the release, but you can follow it on the Beam dev@ mailing list https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@beam.apache.org)

Comment: I am coming back to this, I am trying the TextIO.readAll(), but I can't really understand how to use it, how should I pass the path to readAll()? I need to read all files from a bucket in google cloud

Comment: In this case regular TextIO.read() should be enough and is easier to use.

Comment: The problem is that I needed TextIO.read to returns a PCollection of files, one file per element so then when it gets the parDo we have access to complete element, Thats why I understand that I need the readAll, but how do I pass the path of the bucket in order to read all the files in there?